# Rails 5 how to retrieve strong parameters list (formerly accessible_attributes) from Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters

I implemented the method described in [#396 Importing CSV and Excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true)
which worked fine in Rails 4.

Now I want to do the same in a Rails 5 application. But, it looks like accessible_attributes is deprecated, as I get an `Undefined method accessible_attributes for ...` when trying to use it.

How to smartly retrieve the list of strong parameters now ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta use the controller for whitelisting.

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  ....
end

private

  post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:body, :title)
  end
```